# I need writing a query that will assign a repeat service then keep count for each technician

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains my Service Orders and for the service orders there could be many service troubles.  I need to a query that will get the results as folows:  Joe went to fix a problem and opened service order number 1.  The issue was not resolved, customer calls back. Now Bob goes to fix the issue that Joe didn't resolve.  Out of this Joe is docked a repeat service.  Joe has 1 repeat.  The next day customer calls back: issue is not resolved and Joe goes out to fix the problem.  Now Bob is docked a repeat.  Bob has 1 repeat.  The issue was not resolved and Joe is sent to fix the issue again.  Joe is docked another repeat.  Now joe has 2 repeats.  Issue still not resolves and Bob goes out to fix the problem.  Joe is docked another repeat.  Now Joe has 3 repeats.  Issue still not resolved and Bob is sent out again to fix problem.  Bob is docked a repeat.  Now Bob has 2 repeats and Joe has 3 repeats for the same service order.

I need ideas for how to write this type of query.  Below is a sample of the table:

```
Serv_Trouble    TechID  Tech    ServOrder
ab51            1       joe     1
ccd2            2       bob     1
abd3            1       joe     1
tto4            1       joe     1
mmo5            2       bob     1
abo6            2       bob     1
lll7            1       joe     1
aco8            1       joe     2
dab9            1       joe     2
tof10           2       bob     2
ab11            2       bob     2
cc12            3       larry   2
ab13            2       bob     2
```

Any help will be very, and I mean very appreciated.  I have searched most SQL sites for ideas but non seem to solve something like this.

Comment: What implementation of SQL?  SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL?

Comment: Also do you not have a date field of some sort to track when these calls  take place?

Comment: Sorry am I missing something how do you track that joe and bob worked on the same issue hence the relevant tech sholud be docked as a repeat service

Comment: Mayby you should think about triggers that will update repeat counter when new entry is added. That's the only option when you don't strore dates or any other kind of sorting column, unless this weird Serv_Trouble is some sort of that.

Comment: Bobby I am using Sql Server management studio 2008.

Comment: The table has no dates associated with it.  I asked the DBA and was informed that date has never been implemented in that table.

Comment: The only date exits in the service order table and it is a service order open date and a service order closed date.

Comment: The service order can have many service troubles.  In my table you will see that it contains only 2 service orders.  Service order 1 and 2. Service order 1 has six troubles and service order 2 has 6 troubles.  the troubles are how many times a technician was sent out to service the same service order.

Comment: I don't see any way that you can do this, because you haven't tracked who handled the issue in what order. Unless you have the information stored in another table, you simply don't have the data.

Comment: I researched some more and found out that the actual table will actually look like this:

Comment: Serv_Trouble TechID Tech ServOrder
 1 1 joe        1
 2 2 bob        1
 3 1 joe        1
 4 1 joe        1
 5 2 bob        1
 6 2 bob        1
 7 1 joe        1
 1 1 joe        2
 2 1 joe        2
 3 2 bob        2
 4 2 bob        2
 5 3 larry      2
 6 2 bob        2

Comment: The troubles will be sequential starting with 1 and continuing until the service order is closed.  So i will be able to see which trouble was first by that number sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be looking for a GROUP BY.

```
SELECT
  s.ServOrder
 ,s.TechID
 ,s.Tech
 ,COUNT(*) as repeats
FROM ServOrders s
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      ServOrder
     ,MAX(Serv_Trouble) AS MaxTrouble
    FROM ServOrders
    GROUP BY ServOrder
  ) m ON s.ServOrder = m.ServOrder
     AND s.Serv_Trouble < m.MaxTrouble
GROUP BY s.ServOrder, s.TechID, s.Tech
ORDER BY s.ServOrder, s.TechID
```

Comment: Thank you Rob but that will not work because the repeat count has to be assigned to the previous tech. I Since I found out that the Serv_trouble will actually be a sequential number starting with 1, I think that It will help me assign the count only if there was a sequence prior to the Max sequence.

Comment: thank you, Rob..... I am sure this one will work.  I am trying it now.  You are a life saver.